# mybatis inject Mapper xml while runtime

Tags: java, mybatis

In Mybatis, is it possible to mix java based configuration with xml based mapper?

When configuring *mybatis*, I want to use POJO, since I can configure it at runtime.

When register *mapper* to *Configuration*, I have to generate the *mapper.xml* at runtime.

I know there is

```
 <mappers>
      <mapper resource = "mybatis/Student.xml"/>
 </mappers>
```

which can be embedded into *mybatis* configuration file.

But I am thinking to inject different Mapper while runtime, or even, I want to generate a different Mapper xml file while runtime and inject into *Mybatis* `Configuration`.

Is this possible? if so, How can I do it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add mappers programatically. Suppose you have a mapper called `StudentMapper`. It might have annotations, or there might be a mapping file on the classpath with a matching fully-qualified class name. Then you can add the mapper like this:

```
SqlSessionFactory factory = ...
factory.getConfiguration().addMapper(StudentMapper.class);
```

… and use it like this:

```
Student student;
try (SqlSession session = factory.openSession()) {
  StudentMapper mapper = session.getMapper(StudentMapper.class);
  student = mapper.get(id);
}
```

Comment: yes, Erickson, this is what I am doing now. and by the way, glad to know that SqlSession is self closeable... Thanks!

Comment: _matching fully-qualified class name_ - does this mean the `<mapper namespace=` attribute? Or the name and path of the XML file? I have my XML file in the `resources` directory with a fully-qualified `namespace` attribute but it doesn't seem to be being found.

Comment: It turns out the directory structure + class name needs to match the fully qualified class name.

Comment: @z0r: what did you mean with your last comment? what would be the fully qualified classname of the mapper if the xml-file is called testmapper.xml and was located in /src/main/resources/mapper/? hope to hear from you!

Comment: @KimZeevaarders my memory is hazy but I think it would be `mapper.testmapper`. To follow standard naming conventions, you should probably use camel caps like `src/main/resources/mapper/TestMapper.xml` and `src/main/java/mapper/TestMapper.java`

Comment: @KimZeevaarders I concur with z0r

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can create new Mapper object at runtime by using SqlSessionFactory factory:

xml:

```
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis/mybatis.xml"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

-- updated at 2017-05-09, to load mapper.xml ---
here is the code I found from mybatis-3.4.0-sources.jar!org/apache/ibatis/builder/xmlXMLConfigBuilder

I guess the new mapper.xml files could be parse and register to configuration by

```
InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
XMLMapperBuilder mapperParser = new XMLMapperBuilder(inputStream, configuration, resource, configuration.getSqlFragments());
mapperParser.parse();
```

-- org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.mapperElement(XNode parent) --

```
private void mapperElement(XNode parent) throws Exception {
  if (parent != null) {
    for (XNode child : parent.getChildren()) {
      if ("package".equals(child.getName())) {
        String mapperPackage = child.getStringAttribute("name");
        configuration.addMappers(mapperPackage);
      } else {
        String resource = child.getStringAttribute("resource");
        String url = child.getStringAttribute("url");
        String mapperClass = child.getStringAttribute("class");
        if (resource != null && url == null && mapperClass == null) {
          ErrorContext.instance().resource(resource);
          InputStream inputStream = Resources.getResourceAsStream(resource);
          XMLMapperBuilder mapperParser = new XMLMapperBuilder(inputStream, configuration, resource, configuration.getSqlFragments());
          mapperParser.parse();
      }
      // else 
      // ....
    }
    // else 
    // ....
}
```

here is the process of org.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLMapperBuilder#parse()

```
public void parse() {
  if (!configuration.isResourceLoaded(resource)) {
    configurationElement(parser.evalNode("/mapper"));
    configuration.addLoadedResource(resource);
    bindMapperForNamespace();
  }

  parsePendingResultMaps();
  parsePendingChacheRefs();
  parsePendingStatements();
}
```

Comment: thanks, @treesong, but how to read a mapper xml file and transforming to interface?

Comment: But this *AnotherMapper.class* cann't be generated right? I want to parse and read the *mapper.xml* file, extract the *mapper interface* and register it into *Configuration*. Configuration using POJO, but mapper using xml.

Comment: updated again. I debug through code org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean#buildSqlSessionFactory() to find how it reading the <mapper resource="..." /> node and loading a mapper.xml file, and updated the answer. please try it with you mapper.xml, since I have no any mapper.xml available.